# Single Fault Pulls up Both AND Gate Inputs

Tags: digital-logic, signal, pullup, pulldown, failure

I have a situation where I have 2 inputs to an AND gate coming from 2 sensors (passing through a comparator before). If both signals exceed some predetermined value (let's say 2.5 V for sensor 1, and 1.8 V for sensor 2) then the AND gate should open (and the rest of the circuit should be triggered).

However, if either signal/sensor is disconnected or gives an out of range signal, then the rest of the circuit should still be triggered. I though I could artifically make both signals high if one is faulty and feed them into the gate.

I was thinking of using a pull-up resistor that is somehow "connected" to both signals (so if either is disconnected, then I pull both signals up). I am not sure if this even makes sense or is possible, so any advice would be helpful (or alternative pathways, other than checking if the signal is out of range using 2 comparators per sensor)

Comment: first you need a circuit to detect the fault.